# How do i get jquery accordion working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Need a quick solution to this . Basically I have My HTML like so :

```
<div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
            <div>First content</div>
        <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
            <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

and javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
</script>
```

and include the jquery.js?
But this isnt working. I know this is total noob question. What else do i need to do??

Comment: The first thing you need to do is install Firebug for Firefox, turn the javascript debugging console on, and reload the page to find out where (if anywhere) your errors lie. Edit: Incidentally there should probably be more than one javascript file included on your page, one for jquery itself and one for whatever handles the accordion

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are including jquery, are you also including the jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Firebug for Firefox is defiantly a must. It does look like your issue is that you're not including jquery-ui (it looks like you are using their example for accordion, however).